# How to read JMS messages without consuming them - using ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I would like to know if there is any way to read a jms and actibemq messages without consuming it ??  I know messages can be consumed from the queue , yet still I want ask this question .!!

Answer (score 11):

You can browse Messages on a Queue via the JMS QueueBrowser, or in ActiveMQ you can browse the contents over JMX or with the commands line tools:

[ActiveMQ console tools](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html)

[JMS QueueBrowser API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html)

[ActiveMQ JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html)

Comment: thanks TIM Im planning to write a webservice to implement the functionality ..!!!  so I would be better I could implement the same using plain java code

Comment: I think there is some confusion because the link that "JMS QueueBrowser API" is pointing to is an ActiveMQ page. I think perhaps you meant to share this URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using Message-consumers you need to use the `QueueBrowser` class for doing this:

```java
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
    new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"); 
Connection connection = 
    connectionFactory.createConnection("admin","admin");
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue = session.createQueue("Test");
QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
Enumeration msgs = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
while (msgs.hasMoreElements()) {
    //do your things here
}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I use it in JMeter ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to "consume" the messages but just in a transaction, then when you're done, roll it back, but a browser might be better since that's "what it's for" as it were.

If you're just looking for a particular message, and manual will do, you can  see (I think all, at least some of) the messages and their contents for an activemq by clicking on the "RSS feed" button in the UI. which basically dumps them all to the screen.  The "atom feed" option seems to load faster than the "RSS" one FWIW.

Comment: That's a interesting point of view. Thanks for sharing this.