# ActiveMQ: Check existence of specific message on queue in ActiveMQ SV by CorrelationId

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I use activeMQ server from:

http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html

I have send some message to QUEUE.

I wondering that are there any way to check existence of specific message on queue in ActiveMQ server without consumer the message?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243966/how-to-read-jms-messages-without-consuming-them-using-activemq#comment62678906_14243966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best why to check for the existence of a single message would be to use a QueueBrowser with a message selector.  There are no guarantees though that the browser will return the message depending on how deep the Queue is.

What you are trying to do is an [anti-pattern](http://sensatic.net/messaging/messaging-anti-patterns-part-1.html) and you should really consider using a true Database if you need to query for data.  JMS Queues are meant to house some data which should be consumed rather quickly, there is a very limited feature set around querying for a reason, this is the job of a database.