# ActiveMQ Artemis read messages without consuming it in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, message-queue, activemq-artemis

I want to know if it is possible to read queue messages in ActiveMQ Artemis without consuming or removing it using JMeter.

I have find similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243966/how-to-read-jms-messages-without-consuming-them-using-activemq). But I really don't know how to configure it in JMeter. I'm new in it.

Comment: Why would you want to do performance testing using JMeter without actually consuming messages?

Comment: I am trying to read the messages, then I want to verify if the data in queue are similar to database.

Comment: Is that part of a performance test? If not, why are you using JMeter?

Comment: I don't know what to use as an alternative tool.

Comment: You don't *need* to use any kind of "tool." Just write a simple client. The JMS API is not complex. ActiveMQ Artemis ships with a ton of examples, [including one for a QueueBrowser](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/browser/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/QueueBrowserExample.java).

Comment: but how can I execute this script ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189857/discussion-between-brithwulf-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: This isn't a script. It's a Java program. Did you read [the documentation](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/browser) for the QueueBrowser example that I linked previously? This example (along with many others) is shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis in the `examples` directory.

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out. I have one more question if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal JMS client you'd do this using a [QueueBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html). However, JMeter doesn't support this. It only supports:

- [JMS Publisher](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher)
- [JMS Subscriber](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber)
- [JMS Point-to-Point](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point)